# "Hazard area" or "hazardous area"?

Tags: expressions

What is the more common word combination? Or do they mean different things?
It refers i. a. to explosion protection.

Example:

> hazard area plan

or

> hazardous area plan

Comment: Do either of "hazard area" or "hazardous area" seem to be totally avoided when you try Google searches? Is one vastly more common?

Comment: Thanks Edwin, your hint is fine. For more specialist terms my experience with Google is not the best. My question is directed to those dealing with this (specialist) field like engineers.

Comment: A *hazard area* is more like a single noun, whereas a *hazardous area* is an adjective with a noun.

Comment: The internet examples << technical measures document on the subject of hazardous area classification/ flameproofing. >> and << A Special Flood Hazard Area (SFHA) is an area identified by the United States Federal Emergency Management Agency (FEMA) as an area with a special flood >> both seem to be specialist-domain usages. Specialist lexicons / usages are more appropriately dealt with on relevant specialist websites. On ELU, 'they're synonymous' is probably the answer most people would find useful.

Comment: That's totally not objective, but in my mind, when I see Hazard area I tend to think there's only one probable hazard (it could be flood, fire, electrocution whatever) whereas hazardous area sound like there could multiple sources of danger: a war zone is a hazardous area vs a flood plain is a hazard area. Again, it's just an impression, I'm not saying it's an official definition.

Answer (score 1):

A *hazard area* would be an area that is inherently or naturally hazardous, such that the area itself is a hazard.

A *hazardous area* would be an area that became hazardous due to the introduction of materials, supplies, or other specific activities.

[Source - Hazard Area](http://www.fema.gov/coastal-high-hazard-area)
[Source - Hazard Area 2](http://www.fema.gov/special-flood-hazard-area)
FEMA guides on geographic flood hazard areas

[Source - Hazardous Area](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/hazardous-areas-classification-d_345.html)
 - This engineering site references various classes and groups of typically-man made conditions, materials, and environments.

[Source - Hazardous Area 2](http://www.documentation.emersonprocess.com/groups/public/documents/bulletins/d103222x012.pdf)
 - This guide also references the interaction of various materials and environments.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of Othya read along with the comment of P.Obertelli sums up the issue. However, I'm more inclined to call 'HAZARD AREA' a noun:noun compound or Compound noun.